# How to get middle portion from Sql server table data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I am trying to get First name from employee table, in employee table full_name is like this: Dow, Mike P.

I tried with to get first name using below syntax but it comes with Middle initial - how to remove middle initial from first name if any. because not all name contain middle initial value.

-- query--

```
select  Employee_First_Name as full_name, 
        SUBSTRING(
            Employee_First_Name, 
            CHARINDEX(',', Employee_First_Name) + 1,                
            len(Employee_First_Name)) AS FirstName 
        ---> remove middle initial from right side from employee
```

-- result

```
Full_name Firstname Dow,Mike P. Mike P.
```

--few example for Full_name data---

```
smith,joe j. --->joe (need result as)

smith,alan ---->alan (need result as)
```

Comment: can you make your sample data and your expected output a bit clearer please

Comment: Worth a read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the `len` you need to use `charindex` again, but specify that you want the second occurrence of a space.

```
select  Employee_First_Name as full_name, 
        SUBSTRING(
            Employee_First_Name, 
            CHARINDEX(',', Employee_First_Name) + 1,                
            CHARINDEX(' ', Employee_First_Name, 2)) AS FirstName
```

One thing to note, the second `charindex` can return 0 if there is no second occurence. In that case, you would want to use something like the following:

```
select  Employee_First_Name as full_name, 
        SUBSTRING(
            Employee_First_Name, 
            CHARINDEX(',', Employee_First_Name) + 1,                
            IIF(CHARINDEX(' ', Employee_First_Name, 2) = 0, Len(Employee_First_name), CHARINDEX(' ', Employee_First_Name, 2))) AS FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes the portion before the comma.. then uses that string and removes everything after space.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES('smith,joe j.'),('smith,alan'),('joe smith')) t(fullname)
)

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
        LTRIM(SUBSTRING(fullname,CHARINDEX(',',fullname) + 1,LEN(fullname))),
        0,
        COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(SUBSTRING(fullname,CHARINDEX(',',fullname) + 1,LEN(fullname)))),0),LEN(fullname)))
FROM cte

output
------
joe
alan
joe
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this is most easily expressed using multiple levels of logic.  One way is using `outer apply`:

```
select ttt.firstname
from t outer apply
     (select substring(t.full_name, charindex(', ', t.full_name) + 2, len(t.full_name) as firstmi
     ) tt outer apply
     (select (case when tt.firstmi like '% %'
                   then left(tt.firstmi, charindex(' ', tt.firstmi)
                   else tt.firstmi
              end) as firstname
     ) as ttt
```

If you want to put this all in one complicated statement, I would suggest a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add firstname as (stuff((case when full_name like '%, % %.',
                                  then left(full_name, 
                                            charindex(' ', full_name, charindex(', ', full_name) + 2)
                                           )
                                  else full_name
                             end),
                            1,
                            charindex(', ', full_name) + 2,
                            '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If format of this full_name field is the same for all rows, you may utilize power of SQL FTS word breaker for this task:

```
SELECT N'Dow, Mike P.' AS full_name INTO #t

SELECT display_term FROM #t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser(N'"' + full_name + N'"', 1033, NULL, 1) p
WHERE occurrence = 2

DROP TABLE #t
```